# Replace Missing Values From Gap in Sequence

Tags: arrays, matlab

Suppose you have a sequence of X/Y values where there is a "gap"...

```
resolution = 0.1;
x = [0:resolution:10 10.5:resolution:20];   % 4 missing values (10.1, 10.2, 10.3, 10.4)
y = ones(1, length(x));
```

How can you identify the "gap" in the sequence and replace it with some type of value (e.g. replace it with 0)?

I think this works, but I'm wondering if there is a better way. Also, this method will only work for 1 gap (not multiple gaps). I'm hoping for a simpler method...maybe even a non-looping method.

```
xDiff = diff(x);
calcResolution = min(xDiff);   % Try to calculate original resolution
newY = y;
newX = x;

thresh = 0.000001;
for i=1:length(xDiff)
   % Check any time the difference is larger than our resolution...
   if (abs(xDiff(i) - calcResolution) > thresh)
       gapSize = (xDiff(i) / calcResolution) - 1;
       newY = [y(1:i) zeros(1, gapSize) y(i:end)];
       newX = [x(1:i) (x(i) + calcResolution):calcResolution:x(i+1) x((i+1):end)];
   end
end

% newX == 0:resolution:20
% newY == [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ... 0 0 0 0 ... 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
```

Comment: When there is a gap, how do you define how many values are missing? What should be the step?

Comment: @LuisMendo Good question. I would need to calculate the step. I have been using the smallest value in the diff(), but I also like the idea of using `mode()` from the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
%Assumes the most frequent difference is the resolution
calcResoultion = mode(diff(x));

%Create data set with no gaps
xMin = min(x);
xMax = max(x);
noGapData = [xMin:calcResolution:xMax];

%Create full length of y data
y = ones(1,length(noGapData));

%Round data to mitigate number precision issues from comment
noGapData = round(noGapData * 100) / 100;
x = round(x * 100) / 100;

%Find values in noGapData that are not in x
missingValues = setdiff(noGapData,x);

%Replace 1 with 0 at indicies of missing (gap) values
y(find(ismember(noGapData,missingValues))) = 0;
```

No loops and will work for data with any amount of gaps (assuming the number of gaps is less than the number of data points in the sequence to ensure that `mode(diff(x))` returns the correct resolution.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, `missingValues` returns every value of `noGapData` except 0.

Comment: Could possibly be a number precision issue, I'll have to investigate further.  The documentation looks like `missingValues` should contain just the 'gap' values.

Comment: @David was right about my original answer.  I tested this code out now with the addition of rounding the data and it does identify [10.1, 10.2, 10.3, 10.4] as the missing values

Answer (score 1):

This should work, assuming that (like DaveH) the most frequently occuring gap between elements is the resolution, and additionally that `x` is in increasing order. It's not very nice code, and I am sure it could be improved, but at least (I think) it works

```
d=diff(x);
gapStart=find((d-mode(d))>1e-10);
gap=[x(gapStart);x(gapStart+1)];
gapLength=cumsum(diff(gap)/resolution);
xNew=0:resolution:max(x);
yNew=zeros(size(xNew));
yNew(1:gapStart(1))=y(1:gapStart(1));
for i=1:length(gapStart)-1
    yNew(gapStart(i)+gapLength(i)+1-i:gapLength(i)+gapStart(i+1)-i)=y(gapStart(i)+1:gapStart(i+1));
end
yNew(gapStart(end)+gapLength(end)-i:end)=y(gapStart(end)+1:end)
```